# What is a CSS Authoring framework?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, compass-sass

I were looking for a CSS Framework to help me built website, when I struck with *Compass*.

Now, while I understand what a CSS Framework is, I don't understand what's a CSS **Authoring** Framework.

Expecially, I don't understand if it "replaces" a CSS Framework (like blueprint) or you should use it **with** a CSS Framework.

I'm building a website using Ruby On Rails, and I use SASS but no CSS Frameworks at the moment. If anyone can point me in right direction after answering the question, it will be really appreciated.

**Edit 1:**
Also, which is the difference between a CSS Framework and a CSS Authoring Framework

Comment: It would be nice to understand why I have 1 vote for closing. I think this is a programming question with a direct answer.

Comment: That's the exact reason I stopped posting on here.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme.: Yea, this is happening quite often last period.

Comment: @cimmanon: I'm asking what is exactly a CSS Authoring Framework and the differences between a normal framework. It's like asking what is a library in programming (based on answers received) so yes, it is a programming question because I'm asking about a technology relative to a programming language.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A CSS Framework is (in most cases) a fixed set of basic CSS definitions.
f.e. it brings definitions for some classes which make a basic div-based HTML-layout usable for different screen-widths. (aka liquid layout)

A CSS Authoring Framework (in meaning of Compass) brings no fixed set of CSS definitions. In opposite to a standard CSS Framework, it helps to write CSS rules with various helpers - but you have to write almost every CSS definition by your own. Some examples for helpers: Compass helps you to fix some [common browser issues](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/general/clearfix/) ([IE floats ..](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/general/float/)). And you can [create CSS sprites](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) from existing images with all the CSS definitions on the fly.

You can write your own CSS Framework with the help of a CSS Authoring Framework, or you can simple build on top of a existing CSS Framework.

Comment: Mh, so basically the CSS Authoring Framework is an environment which helps you building CSS, not directly a CSS Framework (which obviusly you can still use with an authoring framework)

Comment: I want to add a comment. After I started using compass I understand exactly what it stays for: Compass is like activesupport for rails, it's a set of helpers that avoids you writing something like vendor prefixes and things like that. It also add some nice helper methods like margin-trailing and similar things. There are a lot of frameworks based on compass which will boost your development, anyway you can use compass with other frameworks quite often. Authoring because it allows you to "compile" your sass code into normal css (at least I think).

Comment: Adding another comment to make the answer more complete, analyzing the "CSS Authoring Framework", it's a framework for **authors** of CSS Framework, so definitely it's used to help you build CSS Frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

CSS frameworks are pre-prepared libraries that are meant to allow for easier, more standards-compliant styling of web pages using the Cascading Style Sheets language.

Layout-grid-related CSS frameworks include Bootstrap, Blueprint, 960 grid, YUI CSS, and other grids.

Like programming and scripting language libraries, CSS frameworks are usually incorporated as external .css sheets referenced in the HTML .

They provide a number of ready-made options for designing and laying out the web page. While many of these frameworks have been published, some authors use them mostly for rapid prototyping, or for learning from, and prefer to 'handcraft' CSS that is appropriate to each published site without the design, maintenance and download overhead of having many unused features in the site's styling.

Somehow, CSS framework == CSS Authoring framework